# How to resolve the function payable issue in ERC20?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "./ERCI20.sol";
import "./newERC20.sol";

   contract timeLock is ERCI20, newERC20 {

     address payable sender = msg.sender;
     address payable benificiary = 0x41194f140110F1D0C5DcE0e2Ef3fC385a38F319b;
     uint256 value = 5;
     uint256 releaseTime;

   function setReleaseTime(uint8 _days) external {
     releaseTime = now + _days * 1 days;
    }
   function release() public payable returns(uint256){
   //  require(block.timestamp >= releaseTime, "Time Error!");
     require((msg.sender).balance > value, "Sender Amount Error");
     require(benificiary != address(0), "Benificiary Address Error");

     //  msg.sender.transfer(value);
       emit Transfer(sender, benificiary, value);
       return (msg.sender).balance;
   }

}
```

[image: remix error]

Comment: How are you sending the transaction? What parameters does the transaction have? How much balance does the sender have?

Comment: this is an erc20 token timelock function, i'm sending this transaction using remix JVM, sender balance is 5000 tokens.

Comment: transaction parameters is an address of receiver, sending value(amount of token) and release time, i want it to send value when certain amount of time meet.

Comment: try using `address(msg.sender).balance` instead of `(msg.sender).balance`

Comment: @LauriPeltonen see the remix console showing me something like this "transact to timeLock.release errored: VM error: revert.
revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance"

function payable: release function is already payable and the balance is also more than those checks

Answer (score 0):

You have a check for `require((msg.sender).balance > value, "Sender Amount Error");`. This checks the *Ether* balance. I assume this is zero for the sender and that's why the transaction fails.

In your comments you mentioned that the sender's *token balance* is 5000 but that's a completely different thing. You can't check token balances with the `balance` property - you have to use `balanceOf` function of the token contract.

Comment: hmm, i have checks there too and the ether balance for this account is 99+ ETH, and the token balance is 5000. but don't know why remix produce this error. by the way i'm creating a contract where i lock some tokens for specific time but without using openzeppelin.